# C# Casting of Dictionary

Tags: c#, containers, generics

I have this function:

```
void WriteMap(object value)  
{  
    IDictionary<string, object> vv = (IDictionary<string, object>)value;  
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> obj in vv)  
    {  
        (write key)  
        (write value)  
    }  
}
```

It works if value is really of type `IDictionary<string, object>`, but it could be anything like:
    `IDictionary<string, int>`
    `IDictionary<string, MyClass>`
    `IDictionary<string, string[]>`
etc.

The cast throws a run-time exception. The function does not modify the container, it only prints the keys and values. Any ideas on how I can make this work? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Add a generic type parameter to your method corresponding to the type of the values in your dictionary:

```
void WriteMap<T>(IDictionary<string, T> dict)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, T> in dict)
    {
        // write key
        // write value
    }
}
```

This has the advantage of eliminating the cast. If you need to pass the dictionary in as an object for some reason, just cast it to [`IDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary.aspx).

Comment: i think this is actually not what Dona is trying to achieve, because you need to know the type for this in order to pass the type to the method.

Comment: @Soren The type `T` can be inferred -- you don't have to declare it explicitly as long as `dict` is a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`.

Comment: okay so u can call it by `WriteMap(dict)`? Didn't know that, sorry. So this is the best way to do it i think => +1

Comment: Thanks for the response. The caller of WriteMap() only has an object because it works with different data types (primitive, array, user defined type, map, etc). So in order to pass it to this generic type method, I will have to cast the object to the specific dictionary type, which is unknown.

Answer (score 1):

Cast it to the non-generic `IDictionary`:

```
IDictionary vv = (IDictionary)value;  
foreach (var key in vv.Keys)  
{  
    var value = vv[key];
}
```

Comment: An class which implements IDictionary<,> doesn't necessarily also implement non-generic IDictionary, so this could fail.  You could make it work by using IEnumerable (which IDictionary<,> inherits), but a generic method would be better still.

Comment: @Jeremy, very good point.  I was under the misconception it worked like `IList` and `IList<T>`.  Agreed that the options you state are better.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is what I ended up doing. @Jeremy, I'm using Dictionary which implements the non-generic IDictionary. I'm curious though, how would you get IEnumerable from the object, I can't make it a generic method because the caller of the WriteMap function only has an object since it works with diff types (primitive, arrays, maps).

Answer (score 1):

First off, why does your function receive `object` as a parameter and then tries to cast it to `IDictionary`? This is extremely bad practice because **the calling code has no idea that the value is to be casted**.

If you only want the function to work with `IDictionary`'es (no late binding magic and stuff), state it explicitly. This is probably the place where you hit the wall: you need it to accept *any* `IDictionary`, right? Perhaps this was the reason you tried to use `object` and casting.

**You should declare your method generic instead:**

```
void WriteMap<TKey, TValue>(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict)  
{  
    foreach (var kv in dict) // kv is KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>
    {  
        // (write key)  
        // (write value)  
    }  
}
```

You can even enforce some conditions on `TKey` and `TValue` if you want to, see [`where` type constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx).

In your case, it seems like key is always a `string` so you can introduce a generic parameter only for value:

```
void WriteMap<TValue>(IDictionary<string, TValue> dict)  
{  
    foreach (var kv in dict) // kv is KeyValuePair<string, TValue>
    {  
        // (write key)  
        // (write value)  
    }  
}
```

One disadvantage of this method is that the compiler must be able to infer `TValue` type during compilation time. If it is not known, or the value types might be different, it might make sense to use non-generic `IDictionary` instead:

```
void WriteMap(IDictionary dict)  
{  
    foreach (var kv in dict) // kv is DictionaryEntry
    {  
        // (write key)  
        // (write value)  
    }  
}
```

Note that in this case key is not restricted to be `string`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The caller of WriteMap() only has an object because it works with different data types (primitive, array, user defined type, map, etc) so WriteMap() has to accept an object. I ended up using IDictionary.

Comment: What I mean is since you *always* cast `object` to `IDictionary` *inside* the method, you should declare method parameter as `IDictionary` and do casting, if necessary, **in caller code**. Method signature is a *contract*, and if method only works with dictionaries, it must be **stated explicitly in contract**. It must be the caller's responsibility provide the method with `IDictionary` and do the casting, if so is required.

Comment: The point is if someone works with your code in future (or if you open a project after a month's break), seeing `WriteMap(object)` declaration wouldn't give one a hint that method actually only works with dictionaries. It will only be obvious after first exception. And even if there was a reason to keep the argument `object` (I seriously cannot imagine one though), you should have added a guard condition that throws an `ArgumentException` if argument is not whatever-you-like. If you don't, the method will throw `InvalidCastException` on casting, and this is exposing implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print out the values, you could use the non-generic [IDictionary interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary.aspx):

```
void WriteMap(object value)  
{  
    IDictionary vv = (IDictionary)value;  
    foreach (DictionaryEntry de in vv)  
    {  
        object key = de.Key;
        object value = de.Value;
        (write key)  
        (write value)  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This works for what I'm trying to achieve.